# Fail to construct instance of imported services in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

[image: Service file]

[image: Calling service]

I create the service and wish to use it in ionic modal. When i want to construct for instance of service, it showed the highlighted error in second picture. Anyone please shred me some light, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the keyword `private` to your `DBService` in the constructor which implicitly adds it as a class member, so you don't need to do a `this.dbservice = dbservice`.

```
constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController, 
            private nav: NavController, 
            private dbservice: DBService) {
    this.priority = "high";
}
```

You need to add that `DBService` to a providers array though. Either in your bootstrap call:

```
bootstrap(App, [/* ..., */ DBService]);
```

or on your root component (App?):

```
@Component({
    providers: [/* ..., */ DBService],
    templateUrl: ...
})
export class App {
```

In you DBServive move the `Storage` variable out of the constructor or Angular will try to resolve it with DI:

```
@Injectable()
export class DBService {
    private storage: Storage;

    constructor() {
        storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
        ...
```

Comment: I did added at ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [DBService]). However, when i try to access saveTasks(item) function of DBService, it gives me the error of "ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Storage! (DBService -> Storage)". Is it i do something wrong at DBService constructor?

Comment: Ah yes, pull it out of the constructor, or Angular will try to resolve it with DI.

Comment: Thanks for your time and kindness! I got it working now, thanks a lot!